# Cannot form a string with a backslash in it when editing a template in yasnippet using lisp command

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing a template with yasnippet.

Writing a equation in latex using {eqnarray} means I will cite it somewhere so I will give it a label. When using {eqnarray*}, there don't need to be a label.

I am new to lisp and yasnippet, so I follow an existed template for c-mode:

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name : printf 
# contributor : joaotavora
# --
printf ("${1:%s}\\n"${1:$(if (string-match "%" text) "," "\);")
}$2${1:$(if (string-match "%" text) "\);" "")}
```

This works out well. Note that there is backslash in this template. My template is:

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: eqnarray
# key: eq
# --
\begin{eqnarray$1}
${1:$(if (string-match "*" text) "\\label{eq:" "")}$2${1:$(if (string-match "*" text) "}" "")}
$0\end{eqnrrary$1}
```

The result will be:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}label{eq:xxx}
XXX\end{eqnarrary*}
```

The backslach expected in front of "label" is missing! When I replace `\\` with `\"` or `\(`, I can get expected result, which means there will be " or ( in front of "label" respectively.

This really confuses me...

Besides I find a logic error in my code...The if command should be `(if (string-match "*" text) "" "\\label{eq:")`. Since this error has misled those who answered my question, I think that I must keep my error here:)

And I just begin to use yasnippet yesterday, I find that this template is really far from practice use, as those comments below pointed out...

Comment: I don't see a backslash in the C template: `\\n` is a newline, and `\(\)` are for the pattern matching. That's one of the joys of emacs lisp, the backslash expansion: each time a string is evaluated, backslashes are expanded. In your case, the backslash is expanded once in elisp, resulting in `\label`, then once again by yas, resulting in `l`. Adding two extra backslashes might do the trick.

Comment: Besides this you really ought to not use `eqnarray` at all.

Comment: Why don't you use `C-c C-e` to insert environments?  Anyway, I second daleif advice not to use `eqnarray` at all.

Comment: If `C-c C-e` doesn't work, install AUCTeX with `M-x package-install RET auctex RET` or use the (dumbed-down) default `latex-mode`, which provides `C-c C-o`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more backslashes!  There are two levels of quoting going on.  As you will notice in the first example to get `\n` it was necessary to put `\\n` in the source.  In your case you need to write `\\\\label`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: eqnarray
# key: eq
# --
\begin{eqnarray$1}
${1:$(if (string-match "*" yas-text) "\\\\label{eq:" "")}$2${1:$(if (string-match "*" yas-text) "}" "")}
$0\end{eqnrrary$1}
```

[I have a relatively new version of `yassnippet` where the old variable `text` is replaced by the newer `yas-text`.]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the [skeleton-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode)

Put this code in your `.emacs`

```lisp
(define-skeleton eqnstar
  "Doc string"
  nil
  "\\begin{eqnarray*}\n"
  "  " _ " \n"
  "\\end{eqnarray*}")
```

Use it with `M-x eqnstar`.