# TextMate 2 + LaTeX bundle. Label snippets for sections

Tags: textmate

I'm trying to modify the code of the section's label.

This is the actual code

```
\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/\\\\\w+\{(.*?)\}|\\\\(.)|(\w+)|([^\w\\\\]+)/(?4:_:\L$1$2$3)/g}}}
${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
% section $2 (end)
```

What this does, is to put the title of the section into the label as you type and change spaces into underscores and every character in lowercase. I want it to also change some latin characters that labels do not support, like:

`a` into `a`

`é` into `e`

`í` into `i`

`ó` into `o`

`ú` into `u`

`ñ` into `n`

This is what it does:

```
\section{Configuración de diseño} % (fold)
\label{sec:configuración_de_diseño}

% section configuración_de_diseño (end)
```

This is what I want it to do:

```
\section{Configuración de diseño} % (fold)
\label{sec:configuracion_de_diseno}

% section configuracion_de_diseno (end)
```

Comment: I don't understand this question

Comment: I never seen before a label like that. I don't understand either what you ask. Could you explain yourself better and add a full MWE?

Comment: This is a question specific about the LaTeX bundle in the TextMate editor for OSX. That is the full code for the snippet, I believe the snippets use ruby, I'm not sure, maybe this is not the place to ask this, but since I saw the TextMate tag I thought I might as well try.

Comment: I think this is off topic here. Better ask in another “programming” site in StackExchange.

Comment: alternatively, you could probably use an engine that supports unicode (such as xetex; use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`)

Comment: Although the problem is off-topic, there are a on-topic solution for that. A LaTeX macro like `\sect{text}` could make the work of this snippet (with any editor) and maintain a clearer text. Edit your question to make it on-topic in order to reopen, if you want this approach.

Comment: Since I can't answer anymore I'll comment here what the crew in Github that supervises the latex bundle for textmate told me, in case someone needs this info. Replacing the code for the labels with this does the trick `\label{ssub:${2:${1/(\w+)(\W+$)?|\W+/${1:?${1:/asciify/downcase}:_}/g}}}` but only in TextMate 2. This is the link [Issue #87](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues/87)

Comment: @Manuel and others: as a newb on this site, I'm puzzled as to why this is any more off-topic than the various emacs/auctex questions that get asked here. There is a textmate tag, after all! Anyone who uses TextMate for LaTeX could have understood the question, in my opinion.

Comment: Here's my opinion: because this is related to TeX in the way that it's a regular expression to be used in TeX, but nothing else. So in fact, it truly has nothing to do with TeX. Better ask in StackOverflow about how to achieve with a regular expression in TextMate the “asciify” and you would probably get an answer (as you got from GitHub, which is quite nice, I do use TextMate too, and I asked some things at SuperUser, StackOverflow and GitHub, even if all of them were related to TeX in a way).

Comment: @AdamMaxwell That said. If this question wasn't about a regular expression, but about how to compile with ConTeXt or, e.g., CSplain from TextMate, or even something about how to call arara or luatex, then I wouldn't have voted to close since that would be truly related to TeX.

Comment: @Manuel Fair enough (and I only tagged you because your name is first). However, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200517/error-adding-new-value-to-latex-math-list-with-custom-function http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194012/auctex-insert-environment-c-c-c-e-no-label-prompt and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188347/cannot-form-a-string-with-a-backslash-in-it-when-editing-a-template-in-yasnippet (plus others). To the outsider, it looks like off-topic is applied inconsistently, to say the least.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Yes, we can't assure consistency in that. There are many, many questions that might be duplicate, many of them that could be closed as unclear, many of them off topic, but still open. Since this is a “voting community” we don't know what led people to vote closing some questions and not others. In my case, since I don't use emacs, I never enter those questions, and I don't care how it (emacs) works (so I don't know what is offtopic and what isn't). By the way: “Anyone who uses TextMate for LaTeX could have understood the question” isn't true, the requisite is knowing *regex*.

Comment: @Manuel Yeah, I actually don't care if emacs questions are voted off-topic or not, since I don't use or understand it :). This looked like a regex issue to me at first, but it turns out that TextMate has this notion of "Format Strings" http://blog.macromates.com/2011/format-strings/ and replacements that's more powerful than just a regex backreference.

Comment: @Manuel I just had a look at the site tour and there it says that you can ask tex specific questions and about related software, since this is specific to typesetting latex and there is even a tag for textmate I don't understand how can this be considered off topic. Nevertheless I tried stack overflow were that question was downright ignored. Thankfully the github crew helped me and now these snippets work like this by default.

Comment: @piptin I'm one out of five who voted for closing, I'm just giving *my* opinion, the reason why I voted for off topic. I don't think this is “specific to typesetting latex”; taking it to an extreme (just so you understand my position, but not trying to give an example) you could post a question here about how to install Windows on your computer, since, in the end, you are going to use it to compile with TeX. By the way, I have always had better luck in SuperUser (and GitHub, of course) than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [regular expression replacement](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions), and I don't think the regex engine supports that kind of transformation. You can match non-ascii, but I'm not sure where you'd go from there with the replacement. I'm also not that familiar with Oniguruma, and it might have that capability.

Unicode diacritic removal is easy to do in Cocoa or Core Foundation with the `CFStringTransform` function, so maybe you could do the replacement via [interpolated shell code](http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets) with a PyObjC program or something.

**Edit**: not sure what protocol is for something marked as on hold; here is the rest of the answer, anyway. As I also use TextMate for LaTeX, I'd like to see a full solution to this, but it might be better on the TextMate mailing list. This is a minimal code example that would be revised to read from `sys.stdin` and write to `sys.stdout`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from CoreFoundation import CFStringCreateMutableCopy, CFStringGetLength, CFStringTransform
from CoreFoundation import kCFStringTransformToLatin, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks
from Foundation import NSString, NSASCIIStringEncoding
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dc = u"a string with düîåçritics"
    dc = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(None, 0, dc)

    sys.stdout.write("original: %s\n" % (dc))
    CFStringTransform(dc, None, kCFStringTransformToLatin, False)
    CFStringTransform(dc, None, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, False)
    ascii_data = dc.dataUsingEncoding_allowLossyConversion_(NSASCIIStringEncoding, True)
    os = NSString.alloc().initWithData_encoding_(ascii_data, NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    sys.stdout.write("modified: %s\n" % (os))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right documentation, I'll read it to see if I can figure something out. Could you perhaps make an example code with the `CFStringTransform` function?

Comment: @piptin I use Sublime Text 2 sometimes and there I've got a similar issue with the labels like you. But is quite simple editing the label manually. Good luck with the snippets.

Comment: Since I can't answer I'll comment here what the crew in Github that supervises the latex bundle for textmate told me, in case someone needs this info. Replacing the code for the labels with this  does the trick `\label{ssub:${2:${1/(\w+)(\W+$)?|\W+/${1:?${1:/asciify/downcase}:_}/g}}}` but only in TextMate. This is the link [Issue #87](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues/87)